Trying to generate Date span between two columns (generating 1 row per month) using CTE
I'm trying to break out a date span from a single row into multiple rows, below is how I would like to see it:
Let's say I have the following data:



Name
MemberID
EFF_DATE
TERM_DATE




John
1234
2020/01/01
2020/03/30



I would love to see:



Name
MemberID
yearnumb
monthnumb
memberall




John
1234
2020
1
2020/01/01


John
1234
2020
2
2020/02/01


John
1234
2020
3
2020/03/01



My current simplified query is:
SELECT 
    Name,
    [MemberID],
    [EFF_DATE], [TERM_DATE]
FROM 
    MYTABLE t
WHERE
    pat_id = '12121212' AND rn = 1

I found this code sample that works exactly how I'd like it to but using my current table/query but I'm not sure how to incorporate the two.
DECLARE @DateStart DATE = '2021-01-20',
        @DateEnd DATE = '2021-01-29';

WITH Extract_Dates_CTE (MyDate) AS 
(
    SELECT @DateStart
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, MyDate)
    FROM Extract_Dates_CTE
    WHERE MyDate < @DateEnd
)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.MyDate) AS RowDateID, 
    a.MyDate AS ExtractedDates
FROM
    Extract_Dates_CTE a;

Instead of using data variables, I would like to use the columns EFF_DATE and TERM_DATE contained in the table that is in my simplified query. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

There's no need for a recursive Common Table Expression here, you can just JOIN to your calendar table. (You do have one, right? If you don't, why not?! Go make one!) Then the solution is literally a simple JOIN on ensuring the calendar date is between the Eff/Term dates, and the Calendar Day is the first day. I don't know what the definition of your Calendar table is, but your statement will likely look something like this:
SELECT V.Name,
       V.MemberID,
       C.CalendarYear,
       C.CalendarMonth,
       C.CalendarDate
FROM (VALUES(N'John',1234,CONVERT(date,'20200101'),CONVERT(date,'20200330')))V(Name,MemberID,EFF_DATE,TERM_DATE) --Obviously this would actually be your table, not a construct
     JOIN tbl.Calendar C ON C.CalendarDate >= V.EFF_DATE
                        AND C.CalendarDate <= V.TERM_DATE
                        AND C.CalendarDay = 1;


Thank you Thom! the only issue I see here is that values are static and it's a dynamic table with thousands of names and date spans. Is it as simple as using the column name instead of the static values 'John, 1234 etc...?

From the solution, @gfuller40 "--Obviously this would actually be your table, not a construct"

Sorry for missing that! - I will try and build a calendar table now...
